# May 13 updates cause major regressions for screen reader users

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility

I am now unable to do anything on the site requiring graphics such as voting or accepting answers. Reputation is also not read properly, mine is read as 856110, I'm assuming badges and actual reputation score are getting merged. This bug is related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49769/may-13-updates-break-accessibility)

Comment: Using CSS to add spaces FTL. Using semantic HTML FTW.

Comment: Duplicate with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49769/may-13-updates-break-accessibility, but as this now has a bounty it can't be closed.

Comment: Not an exact Duplicate since myne deals specifically with screen readers while the other one deals with accessibility in general. I wouldn't have opened this one up if I could have voted on the other one but since I can't I was hoping this would get the admins to comment on weather anything is being done about this.

Comment: @ChrisF: This is no duplicate IMHO, the other one is something that can be worked around e.g. by the video driver. Only the reason for both bugs is a "duplicate" if you will

Comment: & @Tobias - well both problems are caused by the same thing, but I suppose there could be two fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the markup was changed so it went from

```
<span class="vote-up-off" title="..."></span> 
<span class="vote-count-post">12</span> 
<span class="vote-down-off" title="..."></span>
```

to...

```
<span class="vote-up-off" title="...">up vote</span> 
<span class="vote-count-post">12</span> 
<span class="vote-down-off" title="...">down vote</span>
```

and finally to...

```
<a class="vote-up-off" title="...">up vote</a>
<span class="vote-count-post">12</span>
<a class="vote-down-off" title="...">down vote</a>
```

Comment: Hey... you simultaneously fixed the [Opera Mini bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49968/the-envelope-with-new-events-not-visible-on-mobile-opera-mini)!

Comment: @jared yes, we missed accept. That is going in a bit later. edit: has been deployed for a day now with proper accept `<span>accept</span>` text