# No way to upvote/flag a comment anymore?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-voting, internet-explorer-7

I suddenly noticed that today the upvote icon and the flag icon disappeared from all comments on stackoverflow.
I looked at the HTML, they seemed to be there, but my IE7 (running on XP SP3) won't display them.

I do see the number of upvotes for a comment though.

I did all sorts of `Ctrl+F5`'ing and it didn't help.

I also have a stupid feeling it happened after I went from stackoverflow to meta where I wasn't logged in (and probably don't have enough rep to vote up comments) which magically affected my ability to see/use these icons on stackoverflow, too. But it's probably not the case. Just a stupid feeling.

Comment: This is a comment for the purpose of testing.

Comment: Are you sure that you are logged in or that you do not try to vote on your own comments? On the other hand: IE? I beg you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, I can reproduce. This is specific to IE7 and related to the fix we pushed for blind folks.

[May 13 updates cause major regressions for screen reader users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51985/may-13-updates-cause-major-regressions-for-screen-reader-users)

Edit - this was an issue with IE7 not rendering `display:inline-block` correctly for the voting images.

Comment: Please don't undo the change!

Comment: Yeah, just fix it someway :)

Comment: @gserg well one immediate "fix" is to upgrade to IE8, or use Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or even Opera..

Comment: @Jeff Telling users that a fix is to change (or upgrade) browsers is not a fix. Some people are constrained to a particular browsers (company computer for example) and even a portable browser isn't an option. I'm confused though on how IE would break in this situation...

Comment: The fix will be pushed in tonight's deployment.

Comment: Has this been fixed?  I have to run IE7 at work, and I don't see comment voting buttons for either SO or Programmers.