# Stack Exchange isn't well-readable if images are disabled in browser

Tags: feature-request, bug, images, accessibility, alt-text

I had disabled images/Flash/videos in my browser globally for all websites (due to a very low-speed internet in my village). Of course, it also affected SE. Anyway, when I entered SE, the site seems not well-readable.

Neither vote buttons are shown:

> [image: No vote buttons]

Nor main top-bar buttons, and, what's more, I have problems while I'm writing these sentences, as I can't see the editor buttons at all:

> [image: No editor buttons]

So, I think there should be `alt` or `title` attributes for `<img>` tags. Also, notice that many buttons [texts are fully white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPpt5.png), Maybe it's good that with `background: imageUrl` CSS tag, there was also additional `Background-color` or `shadow` behind these texts, which might increase readability when images are not loaded.

Comment: That would really only be beneficial on the first fetch, after that the images only return a 304 Not Modified, and some are even not fetched at all.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68898/how-accessible-are-the-stack-exchange-sites-for-users-of-screen-reader-software

Comment: ["Images don't work if you disable images"](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/763730566701350912)

Comment: That's a Stack Overflow developer. And his tweet is spot on. Your bug report is nonsensical; there's no way to make images display if you've disabled image display.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a bug. Result of disabling images is site shows no images. Of course :-)

Comment: He is not asking that images are displayed with images disabled. He is asking for the buttons to be **still visible in some alternative way** when images are disabled. Still, SO does good use of caching, so I don't agree with the need to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider switching to the mobile web interface (by clicking the "mobile" link in the page footer). I just tested it (by turning images off in my Firefox for Android), and it seems to be fully functional even without images.

As a bonus, the mobile view is optimized for low-bandwidth mobile connections, so it's likely to load faster than the usual desktop version of SE regardless of whether you disable images or not. The down side is that the mobile view lacks some features of the full site view, such as live Markdown preview and the Hot Network Questions sidebar (although some people might consider the absence of the latter a feature).

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the question about whether such a thing is useful or not, this is also something you can fix *yourself* relatively easy. For example you can load this style in your browser:

```css
.vote-up-off,  .vote-down-off {
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size': 14px;
}
```

or if you need more jQuery (we all need more jQuery!):

```js
$('.vote-up-off, .vote-down-off').css({'text-indent': 0, 'font-size': '14px'});
```

There are more things to fix, and you could perhaps use the `content` style to use fancy Unicode icons to make it a bit more like the original with images. But this should give you a start.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering which problem you are trying to solve.

The content of images are just loaded once, every time the browser asks the server if they have been updated (and they have a 7-day cache policy as mentioned by Nick Craver). If not, the content is not sent! SE is moving more and more to SVG, which aren't real images any more.

And also, if you choose to disable images, JavaScript, etc. that isn't really the problem of SE. I don't think is it useful to invest a lot of time, just because you don't want the initial download of images.

Comment: here are the re-load results from this page after it's initial load, with the network throttled on GPRS: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iKSt9.png

Comment: So it is mostly statistics, a few sprites, and the post images. The core images just take a few ms.

Comment: Yeah, but there is still a request going out per resource but I don't expect they want to change that as they can update the site while live, which might require new/fresh image / svg files

Comment: So that isn't important right? The 304 will take care of that as you see in your diagnostics.

Comment: Yeah, but the 304 is still an http call, while the `(from cache)` ones don't require any network traffic at all. So from the OP's perspective they would want to see the number of `(from cache)` increased.

Comment: Not from my POV. I think OP doesn't want to have any images since he thinks that will minimize network load. But it doesn't.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no , you are not right. 
Once i disable images/script in my browser (from settings), i dont want each time i firstly visit any particular domain, to enable the images on first load, then disable it.. and so, i should play  all time i visit some domains first time..

Comment: The 304s mentioned here are people in dev tools, not normal pageloads. We have and use proper cache breakers. Static content is cached for **7 days**, check the headers yourself: `Cache-Control: max-age=604800`. What problem are we trying to solve here? A 7 day cache and breakers seems far more than reasonable to me.

Comment: Indeed, and that for a few bytes @Nick

Comment: well, if you havent read my posts fully, then you cant understand. the problem is not "few bytes", but the problem is that i cant everytime enable/disable the option whenever i visit certain domains first time. thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, but I still fail to see the use of that. The initial few bytes extra you get, is that the issue? Why would you disable images?

Comment: i have exhausted with arguing and cant talk anymore with you, sorry, seems you dont understand that. whenever person disables images in browser globally , then browser wont load images at all, doesnt matter if they are cached or not.

Comment: You could disable Javascript too. Would you argue SE should make a site that works with JS disabled? Images are a core part of the UI, if you disable them it is on you.

Comment: hm.. so, you cant see the difference with JAVASCRIPT disabling and FLESH/IMAGES disabling? quite seems you havent understand my problem, and didnt read. and what's more, do what you want, i just described the drawback of SE, i dont have huge problem with it.

Comment: SE doesn't use Flash, so it are just images. The only reason you give for disabling them is that the internet speed is low, which is only a problem the first time you visit a page. SE works with images, that is how they built it. If you don't like it, then don't use it.

Comment: I like it of course, and will use ;)   ok, forget... you are still talking about first-time visit.